# How do I change the singular/plural on "comment" to "comments" on Facebook's number of comments?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-comments

I would like my subtitles in my Wordpress blog to count the number of Facebook comments on my post. After inserting Facebook's code

```
<span class="comment-count">
   <fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
   </fb:comments-count> comments
</span>
```

I realise that when I only have 1 comment it prints "1 comments", in plural. What changes in the code do I need to do in order to:

- print "No comments" when no comments
- print "1 comment" in singular, when only one comment
- print "X comments" in plural, when more than one comment

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I am completely new to coding (PHP), Wordpress and the Facebook tools.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `fb:comments-count` tag by itself, you can't. What you need to do is get the number of comments into a PHP variable first and then print the correct phrase depending on the value of that variable. You can retrieve the number of comments using the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/), [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), or the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Then, one way to print what you want:

```
 <?php
 $comments = getCommentCountUsingGraphAPI();

 if ($comments == 0) {
    echo "No comments";
 } elseif ($comments == 1) {
    echo "1 comment";
 } else {
    echo "$comments comments";
 }
 ?>
```

But it's a lot easier to compromise and just modify your presentation a little to avoid the pluralization issue entirely:

```
 <span class="comment-count">
      Comments: <fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count>
 </span>
```

Or:

```
 <span class="comment-count" title="Comments">
      <fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the straight PHP method would be using the [ngettext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php) function.

```
<?php
echo ngettext("%d comment", "%d comments", $comments);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined John's solution with [9bugs](http://9bugs.in/get-facebook-like-share-comment-count-given-url-php-248)
 tip with FQL and it works great. Add this to functions.php:

```
 function fbCount($url) {
    $base_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=";
    $query = "SELECT like_count, total_count, share_count, click_count, comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$url' ";
    $new_url = $base_url . urlencode($query);
    $data = @file_get_contents($new_url);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    return $data->data[0];
}
```

Then add this to where you want the comment count to show in content.php:

```
    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $fb = fbCount($url);

     if ($fb->comment_count == 0) {
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '"> leave a comment! </a> ';
     } elseif ($fb->comment_count == 1) {
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '"> 1 </a> comment';
     } else {
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '"> '. $fb->comment_count .  '</a> comments';
     }
```