# How can I make my output say Type and not Types if show_count is less than 2 in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wp-list-categories

So I'm using `wp_list_categories` to output a set of lists and `show_count` is equal to `true` so I can see the amount of posts in that category.

Anyways, I managed to use this code in my *functions.php* and remove the parenthesis around my post counts, wrap it with a span and have it say `"Types"` after the number.

**The problem is that if I have only 1 post assigned to that category it shouldn't be plural and say `"Types"`. If it equals less than 2 it should say `"Type"`.**

Here is my code that I use in my *functions.php* for that:

```
/**
 * filter the wp_list_categories and wrap with <span>
 */

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'mr_modify_archive_taxonomy_query');

$links = add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'cat_count_span');

function cat_count_span($links) {
    $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span class="pull-right">', $links);
    $links = str_replace(')', ' Types</span>', $links);
    return $links;
}
```

I just need to add a conditional in there somehow that defines the `show_count` and have it say:

`if it equals less than 2 echo "Type" else echo "Types"`.

Just having a really hard time giving it this conditional.

Comment: There's a similar answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286964/how-do-i-change-the-singular-plural-on-comment-to-comments-on-facebooks-num

Comment: thanks for the link but that did not help because I understand the logic behind this but I just do not know how to implement it with my code above.

Answer (score 0):

not sure of the structure of $links but you could use `count()` if its an indexed array to get the number of links e.g.

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'cat_count_span');
function cat_count_span($links) {

  $needle ="<li"; // e.g. <li> <a etc.
  $count= substr_count($links, $needle);
  $word= 'Types';

  if($count==1) $word= 'Type';      

  $links = str_replace('</a> (', '</a> <span class="pull-right">', $links);
  $links = str_replace(')', $word.'</span>', $links);
  return $links;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I tried your code and it only seems to out put "Type" even when I have more than 1. I don't know if its your code or maybe the fact that it's a custom post type? not really sure

Comment: when I dump it on my taxonomy.php which is where my categories are listed it gives me Null.

Comment: no put the var_dump inside your filter, it will dump it out when the filter is called. What i think might be happening is links is a array with 1 index and the infomation is the next level down...

Comment: Still defined as Null even when in the filter. I see so how would we be able to access that?

Comment: can you post your current code? $links should not be null if there is links there!

Comment: Well my code that I use to wrap my show count in spans and have it say Types at the end is the same one I have in the question inside my functions.php. I got that code from [HERE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17324/wrap-post-count-in-a-span).

Comment: but showing the var_dump? put it this way, if $links = null inside the filter, you have no links!

Comment: thats weird because the code is doing its job and filtering the show_count category

Comment: make sure the code in your functions file looks like the above!

Comment: Ok now that I copied and pasted the code after your edit it now outputs **string(1783) "** rite above my categories list and I do not see my "Types" unless I remove the var_dump

Comment: ok its not a array, you need to look through that string, try and find something common for each link, eg. `<li>` elements that you can use to identify each link...use the code i've filled in above.

Comment: Their all wrapped in a <span> I guess I could give that a try.

Comment: `<li class="cat-item cat-item-43"><a href="http://localhost/MyWebsite/types/accord/">accord</a> <span class="pull-right">1Types</span>
</li>` that's what it outputs in the list item then repeats for each list item.

Comment: use `<li` i suppose...or span will work too..just change the $needle var above to whatever you want to try!

Comment: hmm strange I used the code and they all still say "Types" even when it is 1 and I tried using the <span and it just all said "Type"

Comment: hmm actually you might be better to use `/li` as using li will count `li` and `/li`

Comment: I think I know what going on. So it still says types with whatever needle I set. But when I do what happens is they all say "Types" UNLESS I go into a category page that displays a list of its sub categories and it so happens to only have 1 sub cat. So if the list only has 1 item to display it will output "Type". In other words I believe it's counting the wrong thing, its counting however many items im displaying and not how many post-types (which are products) are assigned to that specific category.

Comment: well if its a list of <ul> and <li>'s you could count the ul, the problem is you need someway to count these with the filter you are using. Im not too sure what you were saying there but if you want to count category (call it taxonomy) you can wp_query with the relavant terms to count the items. If you have a link ill look and see if there is a simple marker you can use but otherwise it is a whole different subject!